# Evaluate simple condition programmatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I have a list of simple objects:

```
const conditions = [
    {value: true, op: "AND"},
    {value: true, op: "AND"},
    {value: false, op: "OR"},
    {value: true, op: null},
]
```

How can I effectively reduce and resolve this condition so I end up with a "true"?

Ive tried iterating stupidly over them and creating new lists that then get processed again and got quite close, but I wasn't able to get it to work this way and there most likely is a much more efficient way with just one loop or with recursive function calls, but I just cant get it to work right now...

Grateful for any input

Edit: I was able to get to a solution that seems to work. However, it is not very efficient since it always processes all list entries when it could early exit because of boolean logic:

```
const check = (results) => {
    return results.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        if (prev.op === "AND") {
            return {value: prev.value && cur.value, op: cur.op};
        }
        return {value: prev.value || cur.value, op: cur.op};
    }).value;
}
```

Still interested in more efficient approaches

Edit 2: I found a case where this reduce method won't work. I resorted to using simple loops. Using strings as inputs makes the evaluation a lot easier:

```
const checkWithLoops = (test) => {
  const andPairs = test.split("or");

  const andResults = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < andPairs.length; i++) {
    const vals = andPairs[i].split(" ");
    let andRes = true;
    for (let o = 0; o < vals.length; o++) {
      if (vals[o] === "false") {
        andRes = false;
      }
    }
    andResults.push(andRes);
  }

  let orResult = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < andResults.length; i++) {
    if (andResults[i] === true) {
      orResult = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return orResult;
};
```

Comment: That seems like an odd list of expressions. Something like `{op: 'AND', left: true, right: true}` or `{op: 'AND', values: [true, true, true]}` would make sense…

Comment: This list is already simplified/processed. I initially have a list of objects with key/value/operator inside of it. I process the list to resolve the key-value comparison to make it easier, and because I couldnt get it to work without running compare twice on some objects (the compare is rather computatonal expensive). Why is it odd? This list should be processed as if I would make `true && true && false || true`.

Comment: An AST, which kinda seems like what you’re going for here, usually is a tree of expressions. Each expression can be evaluated by itself, and the result is input to a parent expression which can then be evaluated etc, until you’ve evaluated the topmost expression and have a result. Your thing is a weirdly hacked up in-betweener; it basically forms a list of tokens, but structured as individual half-expressions.

Comment: The reason for that is, we only need one level because it would become to complicated for clients to define the rules in a nested way. I dont need to make a tree if I only need one level

Comment: If you only need one level, then you don’t really need to break it up into these weird half expressions. You either have a flat source like `true and true and …`, or you have an expression tree. You can derive the latter from the former. I’m not sure how you got to your format. In your format it’s not even clear how the precedence is supposed to be applied. Is it `true and (false or true)` or `(true and true) or false`?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would make it flat? I dont see how this could be made flatter, its a 1-dimensional array? Also, I thought the AND condition always has precedence over OR when no brackets are applied?

Comment: Again: flat: `true and true or false`, parsed AST: `{op: 'and', left: true, right: {op: 'or', left: false, right: true}}`. Whatever you have… ‍♂️?

Comment: Im really trying to follow and learn but youre clearly nesting objects, on what world is that considered flat? What you described is exactly a tree again. Also, like that, OR would have precedence which doesnt make a whole lot of sense. Again, Im really trying to learn but all you do is suggest stuff without examples that all sound contradicting to me.

Comment: If you think you can get a cleaner solution if you change the way the input conditions are structured, youre more than welcomed to do it and post a working answer. Im really curious

Comment: Yes. Again, you either have a *flat list of tokens*, **or** a nested AST. Some middle ground like you have makes fairly little sense. A list of tokens can be parsed to an AST. An AST can be evaluated. Your thing… could probably be evaluated, but it would be unnecessarily complex to do so, and would leave questions about precedence etc.

Comment: Im not using is "some middle ground". It is a one dimensional array and therefor a flat list. Please show me an example of a flat list according to your understanding? Last time I asked for an example of a flat list you gave an example of a tree. Also, my example doesnt leave questions about precedence. AND has precedence as it should be in a flat condition. I just tested my approach and made another solution with loops. I even used a string of conditions flat as input for both like you suggested to proof that it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-babycat-nf6r4t?file=/src/index.js:641-724

Comment: I was able to find a case where my reduce method wont work. However, your argument of the input being neither flat nor a tree is simply invalid. You can transform my list into a string with a simple loop, which makes it pretty much an equivalent. This also falsifies your argument that the precedence is not clear. Maybe get off your high horse before you claim to know it better.

Answer (score 1):

The current form of `conditions` is a bit odd and there's a good chance you could could benefit from improving your program before this point. And `reduce` is not a good fit because it will iterate thru the entire `conditions` array even when a solution can be determined earlier. However, one solution for the current form is to write a simple recursive `eval` -

```js
function eval(t = []) {
  if (t.length == 0)
    return undefined
  else switch (t[0].op) {
    case "AND":
      return t[0].value && eval(t.slice(1))
    case "OR":
      return t[0].value || eval(t.slice(1))
    default:
      return t[0].value
  }
}

const conditions = [
    {value: true, op: "AND"},
    {value: true, op: "AND"},
    {value: false, op: "OR"},
    {value: true, op: null},
]

console.log(eval(conditions))
// true && (true && (false || true))
// true && (true && true)
// true && true
// true
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. However, it seems not to evaluate everything correctly. (Check the recursive approach in this codesandbox) https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-babycat-nf6r4t?file=/src/index.js

Comment: If the inputs are strings like `"true and true and false or true"` you probably should've shared those. What is the [binding precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for `and` and `or`? Do you want the strings processed sequentially as `true and (true and (false or true))` or do you want to follow the same semantics as JS ie `(true and true and false) or true`? Sometimes the answer is the same, sometimes it's not.

Comment: The question states what the inputs look like. I made them strings to develop the looping approach. In the sandbox you can see I convert the strings to the list/object structure I asked for here, which then gets passed to your function. Without parantheses I wouldve expected that it is clear that AND has precedence over OR since that is the default behavior in all languages I know at least, but yeah maybe I shouldve stated that.